# Dynamically pass props using typescript ENUM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I started learning typescript, using React so trying to create scenarios to practice as I go forwards.

```
export enum Colors {
  Blue = "#0000FF",
  Red= "#FF0000",
  Green = "#00FF00",
}

 export const ColorComponent React.FC<props> = ((props): JSX.Element => {

// props will receive dynamically one of the options (Blue, Red or Green)

return (

        <div className="container">
            <BackGroundColor Color={} />
       </div>

}
```

Is it possible to receive an color throw props, props.myColor, how can I insert myColor into component BackGroundColor using Typescript Colors.Blue for example, where blue should come from the props.

If I pass Colors.Blue it works, but how to send other options.

Objective is receive color string throw props and dynamically set the color into background component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
interface Props {
   myColor: Colors
}

export const ColorComponent React.FC<props> = ((props: Props): JSX.Element => {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <BackGroundColor Color={props.myColor} />
        </div>
    }
}
```

It sounds like you already have the right idea. You just need to define the type of props and then the property is available. And you can continue to add values to the Colors enum as much as you like. The myColor prop will now only accept values from that enum.

```js
<ColorComponent myColor={Colors.Red} />
```